How to display validation error only after form field is touched in Angular reactive forms
I have a component.ts file:
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import {
  FormBuilder,
  FormControl,
  FormGroup,
  Validators,
} from "@angular/forms";
import { FaIconLibrary } from "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome";
import { fas } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

@Component({
  selector: "app-course-form",
  templateUrl: "./course-form.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./course-form.component.scss"],
})
export class CourseFormComponent {
  constructor(
    public fb: FormBuilder,
    public library: FaIconLibrary
  ) {
    library.addIconPacks(fas);
  }

  profileForm = this.fb.group({
    title: ["", [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)]],
    description: ["", [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(10)]],
    author: ["", [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$/)]],
    duration: [0, [Validators.required, Validators.min(1)]],
  });

  courseForm!: FormGroup;
  title = new FormControl("");
  description = new FormControl("");
  author = new FormControl("");
  duration = new FormControl(0);

  authors: any[] = [];
  durationText: string = "";
  submitted = false;

  removeAuthor(author: string) {
    this.authors = this.authors.filter((a) => a !== author);
  }

  getDurationFormatted(minutes: number): string {
    const hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
    const mins = minutes % 60;
    return `${hours.toString().padStart(2, "0")}:${mins
      .toString()
      .padStart(2, "0")}`;
  }
}

and html component:
<h2>Create / Edit Course</h2>
<form [formGroup]="profileForm">
  <div class="app-plate">
    <div class="course">
      <h3>Main Info</h3>
      <div class="form__control">
        <label for="title">Title</label>
        <input type="text" id="title" placeholder="Input text" />
        <span
          *ngIf="profileForm.invalid"
          id="titleErrorMessage"
          class="text-danger"
          >Title is required.</span
        >
      </div>
      <div class="form__control">
        <label for="description">Description</label>
        <textarea
          id="description"
          placeholder="Input text"
          rows="4"
          cols="5"
        ></textarea>
        <span
          *ngIf="profileForm.invalid && profileForm.value.description"
          id="descriptionErrorMessage"
          class="text-danger"
          >Description is required.</span
        >
      </div>
      <div class="separator"></div>
      <h3>Authors</h3>
      <div class="form__control">
        <div class="course__flex">
          <input type="text" id="author" placeholder="Input Author Name" />
          <app-button
            id="createAuthor"
            button_text="Create author"
          ></app-button>
        </div>
        <span *ngIf="" id="authorErrorMessage"
          >New author should contain only latin letters and numbers.</span
        >
        <div class="course__authors">
          <ul class="authors-list">
            <li
              *ngFor="let author of authors; track: author"
              class="authors-list-item"
            >
              Id: {{ author.id }}. Name: {{ author.name }}
              <app-button button_text="Remove" (click)="removeAuthor(author)">
              </app-button>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="separator"></div>
      <h3>Duration</h3>
      <div class="form__control">
        <div class="course__flex">
          <input
            type="number"
            id="duration"
            placeholder="Input duration"
            formControlName="duration"
          />
          <div class="course__duration">
            <strong> </strong>
            hours
          </div>
        </div>
        <span *ngIf="" id="durationErrorMessage" class="text-danger"
          >Duration is required and must be greater than 0.</span
        >
      </div>
      <div class="form__action"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<div class="buttons-container">
  <app-button button_text="Cancel"></app-button>
  <app-button button_text="Create course"></app-button>
</div>

I want to show:
 <span
          *ngIf="profileForm.invalid "
          id="titleErrorMessage"
          class="text-danger"
          >Title is required.</span
        >

only when the input field was touched and is still invalid. Now the error is showed on the loaded fresh new form. How to do it?
following:
touched and valid using reactive forms in Angular
I tried using form control like:
 <div class="form__control">
        <label for="title">Title</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="title"
          placeholder="Input text"
          [formControl]="title"
        />
        <span
          *ngIf="profileForm.invalid && profileForm.controls['title'].touched"
          id="titleErrorMessage"
          class="text-danger"
          >Title is required.</span
        >
      </div>

But it didnt work.

The validation for the title control is not correct because you should validate the specific control, not the whole form, like this:
<span
   *ngIf="profileForm.controls.get('title').invalid && profileForm.controls.get('title').touched"
    id="titleErrorMessage"
    class="text-danger"
 >Title is required.</span>

If you are using Angular version 14 or more, you can have strong typing for your form which is a great feature for avoiding bugs:
<form [formGroup]="form">
   <label for="name">Enter name</label>
   <input type="text" id="name" formControlName="name" />
   
    <!-- new control flow using @if -->
    @if(form.controls.name.invalid && form.controls.name.touched) {
    <span style="color: red">Name is required or invalid</span>
    }

   <!-- or the old way using ngIf -->
   <span *ngIf="form.controls.name.invalid && form.controls.name.touched">Name is required or invalid</span>
</form>

component.ts
interface MyForm {
  name: FormControl<string | null>;
}


@Component({...})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  private _fb = inject(FormBuilder);
  protected form!: FormGroup<MyForm>; //form of type MyForm

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form = this._fb.group<MyForm>({
      name: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      city: new FormControl(null) // you'll get an error because "city" is not defined for type MyForm
                                 // strong typing in action
    });
  }
}

Take a look at the demo

hi, thanks for answer! but i think there sould be an easier way of doing it without interface MyForm

There is no need to use an interface, I only showed you that because it is way better to do it like that, you can type safety in your forms. The first part of my answer is showing you what you had wrong
